# Running software on linux through Wine

Tags: linux, java, wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running software on linux through Wine](https://superuser.com/questions/198685/running-software-on-linux-through-wine)

Our school is setting up a Linux computer lab for students to use. We have Kinetic Books and would like to run it on these computers. The software is java-based, but not purely so. Is it possible to run it under Wine? Are there any general rules-of-thumb for which programs are Wine-compatible?

Thanks!

Comment: `for which programs are Wine-compatible?` - you can check appdb http://appdb.winehq.org/

Comment: Thanks, it's not on there, but its not a hugely common program, and that seems to be a list of only verified programs...

Comment: You could try running it with wine to see how it works.  At the very least you'll have an error message or two where the program went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't run out of the box and you get error messages, don't just give up. A lot of applications need additional libraries that aren't installed by default but can be added easily with winetricks. See this page for details:
http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks