# Running software on linux through Wine

Tags: java, linux, wine

Our school is setting up a Linux computer lab for students to use. We have [Kinetic Books](http://www.kineticbooks.com/support/sup_tech1.html) and would like to run it on these computers. The software is java-based. Is it possible to run it under Wine? Are there any general rules-of-thumb for which programs are Wine-compatible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to install a windows jvm under wine if the software uses native libraries. A linux jvm wont be able to load dlls nor access the api provided by wine.

[Winehq](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=6626) lists a current jvm as fully working, so there shouldn't be any problems with running java itself in wine.

Answer (score 2):

after install wine type wine name.exe in terminal

Comment: What does that do?

Comment: it executes the program as if it were in a windows environment

Answer (score 0):

You can goto http://appdb.winehq.org/, have a look and good luck.